# Как сохранить всех слушателей события после перезагрузки сервера в Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, события

У меня функция, которая выполняется каждые 24 часа. Она емитит событие. Но если я перезагружу сервер, все слушатели пропадут. Что можно сделать?

Comment: А слушатели навешиввются по какой-то логике? При первом старте сервера их нет?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: сохраняйте время последней перезагрузки в файле/базе и смотрите не на "setInterval(...)" а на время последней отправки и прошло ли "N часов"